# Error importing H5PY "undefined symbol: H5FD_mpio_init"

Tags: python, linux, hdf5, h5py

I've installed H5PY, but when trying to import the h5py module, I get this error:

```
>>> import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matteo/Downloads/h5py-2.4.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from h5py import h5a, h5d, h5ds, h5f, h5fd, h5g, h5r, h5s, h5t, h5p, h5z
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/h5py/h5f.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/h5py/h5f.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 26, in init h5py.h5f (/home/matteo/Downloads/h5py-2.4.0/h5py/h5f.c:5160)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/h5py/h5fd.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/h5py/h5fd.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /home/matteo/.python-eggs/h5py-2.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/h5py/h5fd.so: undefined symbol: H5FD_mpio_init
```

Then, if I try again to import h5py, I get a different error

```
>>> import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/matteo/Downloads/h5py-2.4.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from h5py import _errors
ImportError: cannot import name _errors
```

I am in a different directory than the installation directory.
Can you help me?

Comment: How did you build them (h5py and HDF5)? As it looks like h5py was built for parallel (MPI IO), while HDF5 wasn't. Or it could be the other way around.